# Memory issues when running Keras inside Docker on a Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, keras, docker-machine

Running a Keras training algorithm results in various memory issues, when running it inside a Docker machine on a Mac.

- Training algorithm works fine on the same machine outside Docker
- Setting Docker Memory from 1 GB to 8 GB (limit of the machine) doesn't help
- Maximum Video Memory: 128 MB
- Different TensorFlow (`0.10.0` and `0.11.0`) and Theano backends pulled from Docker all show similar errors
- The list of other Docker processes  that might be conflicting `docker ps -a` is empty

The problem is that I'm getting **much lower performance** running the **same training algorithm** on the **same machine with Docker**. All the errors point to **memory management problems**:

1) The original erroror was **MemoryError**, when running the training script during the container's `docker build` process and it exited the process before training even began.

2) Now I'm getting **ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,64,254,254]** after running `docker run 058785edc11d python train.py --run` once the container was build (seems to go one step further):

```
Training..
Train on 385 samples, validate on 40 samples
Epoch 1/1
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1046, in fit
    callback_metrics=callback_metrics)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 784, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 641, in __call__
    updated = session.run(self.outputs + self.updates, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 382, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 655, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 723, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 743, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,64,254,254]
     [[Node: transpose_2 = Transpose[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Conv2D, transpose_2/perm)]]
Caused by op u'transpose_2', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 138, in <module>
    run(extract=extract_mode, cont=continue_)
  File "train.py", line 79, in run
    model = m.get_model(n_outputs=num_categories, input_size=size)
  File "/tmp/model.py", line 24, in get_model
    conv.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(3, input_size, input_size)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 110, in add
    layer.create_input_layer(batch_input_shape, input_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 341, in create_input_layer
    self(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 485, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 543, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 148, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 341, in call
    filter_shape=self.W_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 997, in conv2d
    x = tf.transpose(x, (0, 3, 1, 2))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1051, in transpose
    ret = gen_array_ops.transpose(a, perm, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2489, in transpose
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Transpose", x=x, perm=perm, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2310, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1232, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

3) After removing the exited docker containers, reducing training batch size I'm getting **std::bad_alloc**:

```
Training..
Train on 404 samples, validate on 21 samples
Epoch 1/1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

4) Another common error **Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25088,4096]**

```
$ docker run f825faab715c python train.py --run --continue
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Using TensorFlow backend.
/tmp/data.py:134: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  val = np.random.choice(dataset_indx, size=number_of_samples)
/tmp/data.py:127: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  train = np.random.choice(dataset_indx, size=number_of_samples)
Loading data..
Number of categories: 2
Number of samples 425
Building and Compiling model..
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:936] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25088,4096]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:936] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[4096,4096]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:936] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25088,4096]
     [[Node: gradients/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=true, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](cond_5/Merge, gradients/add_43_grad/Reshape)]]
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25088,4096]
     [[Node: gradients/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=true, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](cond_5/Merge, gradients/add_43_grad/Reshape)]]
Training..
Train on 404 samples, validate on 21 samples
Epoch 1/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 138, in <module>
    run(extract=extract_mode, cont=continue_)
  File "train.py", line 100, in run
    sample_weight=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 405, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1046, in fit
    callback_metrics=callback_metrics)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 784, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 641, in __call__
    updated = session.run(self.outputs + self.updates, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 382, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 655, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 723, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 743, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25088,4096]
     [[Node: gradients/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=true, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](cond_5/Merge, gradients/add_43_grad/Reshape)]]
Caused by op u'gradients/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 138, in <module>
    run(extract=extract_mode, cont=continue_)
  File "train.py", line 100, in run
    sample_weight=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 405, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1031, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 658, in _make_train_function
    training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(trainable_weights, self.constraints, self.total_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 307, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 48, in get_gradients
    grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 666, in gradients
    return tf.gradients(loss, variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 478, in gradients
    in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py", line 637, in _MatMulGrad
    math_ops.matmul(op.inputs[0], grad, transpose_a=True))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1346, in matmul
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1271, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2310, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1232, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

...which was originally created as op u'MatMul', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 138, in <module>
    run(extract=extract_mode, cont=continue_)
  File "train.py", line 79, in run
    model = m.get_model(n_outputs=num_categories, input_size=size)
  File "/tmp/model.py", line 70, in get_model
    conv.add(Dense(4096))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 142, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 485, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 543, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 148, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 628, in call
    output = K.dot(x, self.W)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 214, in dot
    out = tf.matmul(x, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1346, in matmul
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1271, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2310, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1232, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

Comment: Did you know "what is maximum length of hash indexes ". You already got initial hash address on memory allocation. Python can't follow symbolic index of ram if large than XXXXXX bits. I want to learn what is XXXXXX value ?

Comment: Is your container exiting?

Comment: What do you see when you do docker ps -a? Share screenshot.

Comment: @Techiee `docker ps -a` shows a lot of exited containers and the active one on top. Screenshot added.

Comment: After building the docker container I run it through `docker run 6a12c8d92084 python train.py --run` the container goes to `exited` status after the script crash.

Comment: @dsgdfg I don't know that value precisely unless there is some universal maximum in Python, but I will post it once I will find out.

Answer (score 1):

May be your training algorithm needs more memory than 8GB. I have faced such issues before, but increasing the memory has always solved problems. Your error **ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,64,254,254]** clearly indicates that you have run out of resources and that it would need more memory to run your application.